# How to share a type between two WSDL or more?

Tags: xml, xsd, wsdl, wsimport

I have to write 2 web services in java in a top down way, that is starting to define the WSDL.
The 2 WSDL share the same targetnamespace, and share some types. If I duplicate these types in each WSDL, I get a wsimport error because these symbols are defined twice. But if I define these types in one WSDL only, the other is not correct.
I have tried to define these types in an external XSD file, that I have included in the WSDL files. But it doesn't change anything. wsImport keeps on generating these types twice.

There should be a way to declare a type in a WSDL without defining it, meaning that this type is defined elsewere. But I don't know how.